# SDLNet detect not existing host

Tags: sdl, sdl-2, sdl-net

`SDLNet_ResolveHost` always return 0 no matter if there is any host on that IP and port. According to the documentation it should return -1 when an error occurs.

How can a non existing host be detected?

Comment: So it's returning `0` for something blatantly non-existent like `"invalid"`?  Or are you using an IP string like `"4.4.4.4"`?  I'd expect the IP strings to always "resolve", since there's nothing really to do other than check that the IP isn't malformed & populate `address.host`.

Comment: @genpfault It return zero on a IP that could be real, but doesn't contain a host answering. So I have to rename my question, I want to know if the host exists and is ready for answers.

Comment: Well, you have to actually try a `SDLNet_TCP_Open()` to figure that out, `SDLNet_ResolveHost()` only resolves stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution. `SDLNet_TCP_Open` will return `NULL` when an error occurs.